# First person 'I' and 'we' used in same paragraph

Tags: grammaticality

The protagonist often switches between I and we (royal we). But I'm not sure if it's grammatically correct to switch in the same paragraph.

Edit

Two of many similar examples:

"I loved your father, and we love ourself." Shakespeare.

"Yet I here roundly assert, that they can be nothing to the purpose, against what I have advanced - we (ourself) know him better than any of his contemporaries could know him, and when I examine..." The Gentleman's Magazine 1732

Comment: Do you mean grammatically correct or semantically meaningful? You can replace every subject with any valid subject you want and the grammar will still be good, but the meaning will change.

Comment: Deliberately choosing to have your character speak in an inconsistent and confusing way might make the question of whether or not it's grammatical kind of moot.

Comment: As already mentioned, grammar is less of a point. Your book will have no value if you do not properly master that way of speaking. And a research of 2 short quotes does not even count as a start. To be able to deliver speach(es) in the book in that "tongue", you need to properly learn that tongue - to the level that you think in it and dream in it. Otherwise, you might just look like an impostor. The "Writing" Stackexchange site is probably a much better place for that endeavor.

Comment: @virolino That 'tongue' is consistent throughout the book - the singular I for a more personal expression, the plural we for a haughty majestic manner of speech. The quotes are relevant to what I'm asking - they answer my question. Perhaps I should have done my research before wasting my time reading experimenter-generated answers for no good purpose.

Comment: I have no problem agreeing that the quotes might be good. I am just saying that switching between "I" and "majestic We" so quickly and so often, is going to be dazzling. Please also remember that the same "majesty" might use "we" to refer to himself and his own people together - as opposed to them (e.g., the enemies). So you end up with a salad of "I", "we" and "majestic we"...

Comment: @virolino Yes, another way to say what I said. What I don't get is that if someone is hellbent on something, it's hard to convince them otherwise even if there are arguments to the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the paragraph, the I and we is grammatically fine but pragmatically wrong. *AS*: The I refers to you whereas the we would refer to "all people".

It doesn't work to try and use a *royal we and I* in the same paragraph.
The reader will not understand that they both mean you.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is about what grammatical person to use in a paragraph (or rather switching between two).

Comment: 'Ourself' is mentioned in the example - the royal we. So clearly I and we refer to the speaker.

Comment: @Lambie: I agree with Laurel. The first part of your answer is quite far from the question (at least in the way it is written). If you just delete it, I fully agree with the second part and you get my vote.

Comment: @virolino Yes? Funny thing, I completely changed my answer after reading her comment so her comment no longer applies. Neither does yours, in fact. **The point is this, and I repeat it: You can't use a royal we and I pronouns in the same paragraph to refer to yourself as author or narrator.**

Comment: @Lambie Have you looked at the quotes in my edited question?

Comment: @Legion The Bard, and the other chap, are in fact making a **statement about power**. They are very clear about that. They are not writing a paragraph in a book with a narrator changing between one and the other on a whim.

Comment: @Lambie Your wriggling to get off the hook. The FACT is I and we (first person plural) are used not only in the same paragraph but in the same sentence.

Comment: @Legion I am sharing with you my knowledge of writing. I am not trying to get off a hook. Often, people who are not linguists don't consider what I would call a fuller picture. "Verging on sanity"? The author creates the narrator's voice. "Peccadillos of peculiar grammar people"? What are grammar people?